# What is one word for describing the feeling when you are "overwhelmed" from eating something rich or too sweet

Tags: single-word-requests

Sometimes you eat something that is too cheesy or too sweet and you can't eat too much of it - not because you are full but because you feel "overwhelmed" by the taste. Is there a word that describes this feeling?

Comment: Not sure about the feeling but the food was [**sickly²**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sickly).

Comment: **Overwhelmed** *is* the exact word. You are always overwhelmed by something: "I am overwhelmed by its richness." There is no word that specifically means "overwhelmed by richness." You use it in the question, and it describes the feeling just as it should. There is no better word for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cloying** is a possible candidate -- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/cloying):

> too sweet and therefore unpleasant

Or [Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cloying):

> disgusting or distasteful by reason of excess

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I am a little curious why it got two downvotes.

Comment: *Cloying* seems to have negative connotations not present in the statement of the question. I'm curious how the questioner would use *cloying* in a sentence.

Answer (score -2):

To  be ovewhelmed/overcome¹ by the headiness of sth (*mild dislike but not necessarily*)

> (SOED) heady: apt to intoxicate

- [The Flavour Thesaurus](https://books.google.fr/books?id=4Lqac85K3JcC&pg=PT45&dq=%22headiness%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGv4iht_DoAhVWDmMBHX99CaQQ6AEIswIwHA#v=onepage&q=%22headiness%22&f=false) Niki Segnit - 2010
  Its bitter, tannic quality is apt to cut through the fatty headiness of the cheese, and its sweetness peeps through too.

---

To find the taste of sth (slightly) offensive

> (SOED) offensive: disgusting; nauseous

---

To be slightly nauseated by the taste of sth
To feel slightly nauseous from the taste of sth

---

To be sickened by the taste of sth (*strong dislike*)

> SOED: feel nausea, loathing or disgust

¹<sub>Addition after **user Isabel Archer's** comment</sub>

Comment: I think using the word "overcome" might work as well. I still feel with both that something is missing. "Overwhelmed" may have a slight positive connotation. "Overcome' doesn't have that problem,but it may not be right either.

Comment: @IsabelArcher In fact those two word are synonyms (that's what  the OALD tells me).